# Scratches on Metal

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I know that there are answers to this question already but i tried doing the one answered by Gandalf 3 and this is what it looks like:[image]

[image]
3d view

[image]
my node,

i love the look of it but i want to get rid of that blue shine and make the scratches not just get tiled, could anyone please help me?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51900/how-to-simulate-a-dented-surface-for-metal/51908#51908

Comment: Please spend a few more minutes expanding on your questions. Add images of your current material setup and compositing nodes. Adding more information on the questions will help others give you faster and precise answers. Consider also uploading your file. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ If you are making reference to other posts please add the link to it as well.

Comment: You can make a procedural texture(never tiles)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4BhdrFDHkQ    Or you can sculpt the scratches http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52127/what-is-the-workflow-to-sculpt-construction-lines-using-the-curve-stroke-method

Comment: As is visible from nodes and image, the image texture was used for scratches. To get rid of tiles you will have to make that image texture tileable. You can use photo editors' plugins or do that manually.